# PHP sanitize strings used inside PHP PDO connection

Tags: php, validation, input, pdo, sanitization

I have a `dbconfig.php` file which contains the **MySQL** database name, host, username and password to connect to the database.

```
// dbconfig.php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$db_name = 'mydb';
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name.';charset=utf8', $username , $password);
```

I have a HTML form which allows you to set from the UI the database credentials, so the strings above come from user input and are saved directly into this file by writing them when the form is submitted.

How can I sanitize the strings so that it can't be exploited? Currently I write the strings like this:

```
function sanitizeStr($string) {
    $string = str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $string);
    return var_export($string, true);
}

$pattern = "/\\\$host = .*;/";
$newpat = '\$host = ' . sanitizeStr($_POST['db_host']) . ';';
$contents = preg_replace($pattern, $newpat, $contents);

// ... same for $username, $password and $db_name
```

Are `str_replace` and `var_export` enough to stop code from being injected into `dbconfig.php`?

I can not try a really aggresive sanitization (such as allowing only specific characters) because this would force the user to have a MySQL password which only contans those characters.

How can I make sure that the string from the input will only be used as strings inside the PHP file and not somehow as valid code?

Comment: How is it a duplicate? That talks about sanitizing user input inside PDO quries, this is about sanitizing user input store inside a PHP file? It is not related to SQL.

Comment: Why would you want to "sanitize" this input? Against what? Someone who provides the credentials apparently already has the full control. One don't have to break into the house, if he has the key.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Because this happens on initial setup of a script. If an attacker happens to be there at the same time, he could execute his own code before you enter your database credentials. Once the data has been entered the form disappears.

Comment: Plus, my use-case is not really relevant, the question is how to sanitize user input stored inside a PHP file.

Comment: And how do you distinct a real user from an attacker if no credentials are set yet?

Comment: if your question is how to export a variable then the answer is to use var_export(). I don't really get what's the purpose of str_replace though

Comment: @YourCommonSense I suppose if someone inputs password like `pass'; exec('rm -rf .'); //`. And OP puts it into a file as is - the file will clear the home dir.

Comment: @u_mulder The form is publicly accessible only before the correct database connection information is stored. Once the credentials are entered, the form disappears. If somehow an attacker manages to get to this form between the time you upload the script and by the time you enter your database information, I don't want him to be able to execute any code. If he enters connection information to another database the problem is not as bad, until I find a better solution for the initial setup.

Comment: @YourCommonSense My question is how to safely write the value of `USER_INPUT` in `$host = 'USER_INPUT';`. @u_mulder mentioned an example of a possible attack.

Comment: You can think about it  "how to prevent PHP injection".

Comment: Then I already changed the dupe target that should satisfy your needs

Comment: Also I suggest storing credentials not in php file. But maybe in some plain txt,ini,json config.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have also asked in my question if the `var_export` I use is enough, but recently someone suggested that it might not be enough.

Comment: Then ask someone to prove their point

Comment: @u_mulder This dbconfig.php is executed on every request, so I thought that would affect performance. Also, does that actually solve the problem? The values are still used inside the PDO connection string, but I assume in that case PHP will automatically conver them to proper strings.

Comment: @YourCommonSense That's what I was asking here. Either a reassurance that `var_export` is enough, or an example where it is not and a better sanitization function. I doubt the question was a duplicate of the marked one though.

Comment: and you already got your answer through a duplicate

Comment: @YourCommonSense In answer of the question marked as duplicate there is even a comment: `Bad way, because problem with security. You can included some code with vulnerability.`. I don't understand how the duplicate is relevant just because the answer is the same. It's like I'm asking "what is 4+5" and you link to the question "what is 3*3" just because the answer is the same.

Comment: Stack Overflow is about answers, not comments. The answer provided covers your issue.

Comment: Don't store config in an executable format in the first place and you won't have to worry about problems like this. Dump it into a format like JSON.

Comment: @Sammitch But isn't it a performance issue to read this config on every database query?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Thank you! I see they only use `addcslashes` to sanitize the input.

Comment: No. Go write an example config file, then write a script that has a loop that reads it 1000 times, and then watch it finish so fast that you question whether it ran at all.

Comment: @Sammitch I know WordPress is not a good example, but as mentioned above, [they use the same way](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/setup-config.php#L372) of storing their DB credentials. It's used on many sites, so maybe it's not that bad.

Comment: @Sammitch how about exposing the database credentials to anyone who would request a file? Call it secure? Seriously?

Comment: Wordpress stores _their own_ config, and might dynamically write it _once_ at install time when only the _admin_ is touching it. To say nothing of the flaming heap of bad practice that WP is in general. If you want to take user input from internet randos and put it in executable files, that's your funeral. It's not like you see 30+ comment threads on how _good_ an idea is here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @XCS you are about to make a mistake, using some ugly hack instead of a specialized function intended for the purpose. Just a friendly warning.

Comment: @YourCommonSense What do you mean? I am already using `var_export`. The `addclashes` was just a remark.

Comment: @Sammitch In my case it's the same. It is the admin's own config for the platform. It's not intended to be public, but the admin needs the interface for the initial setup. On WordPress you have the same attack possibility, to go and fill in the initial setup form before the admin does.